# DocuSign: Migrate User from group to group from Account to Account via AdminAPI

Tags: powershell, docusignapi, idm

I am currently connecting our IDM via Powershell to the AdminAPI of Docusign. While reading in works fine, I have problems wir Movers - so if a person switches group within the same account or switching accounts.
Accounts represent geographical Areas and groups production locations.

Is there an elegant and suggested way through adminAPI?

I know that I can close the old Account with group and create an assignment for the new account as well as I can close the account with the old group and re-open it with the new group. there is the flag for the request body I found here but nowhere in the Docu "sentactivation": true which reopens a membership.

But especially in the use-case 'group to group' the user would be closed at all for a short period.
I always can add a second group, but I don't know how to delete the first one.

So my questions (AdminApi):

- How to close and open groups within an Account for a user?
- Is there any other way to switch accounts besides closing Account Membership A and Activate account Membership B? (Like a migration)
- How is it possible to create active users and account assignments through API? (status: active vs status:activationSent)

Thanks!